# .click(function) not working for $.getJSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I want to trigger the Controller Action when I click on a button, and I tried to implement some JQuery code to do that, however the click is not triggering properly.

I have the following code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnLoadData").click(function() {
        var ResXName = $('#ResXName').val();
        var LangID = $('#LangID').val();
        var url = "../Home/LoadResXFile";
        e.preventDefault();  
        $.getJSON(url, { value: ResXName, langID: LangID }, function (data) {
            alert('clicked!');
        });
    });

});

</script>

<div class="main-content">
<input type="button" id="btnLoadData" value="Load Data" />
</div>
```

When I move the alert above the $getJSON, it works, so the button is being clicked correctly, however when I move the alert inside the $getJSON, I am not getting any alerts, and also the controller action is not being triggered.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: The getJSON call is asynchronous, and the alert should fire within some seconds. Do you know the getJSON is actually working and returning?

Comment: What reason you have for `e.preventDefault();` Guess this breaks your function.

Comment: I did remove the e.preventDefault() but still not working.  Clearly th problem is the URL, however I have used that same pattern on a different project for a change in dropdownlist and it worked fine.

Comment: Have you debugged it using Firefox + FireBug or Google Chrome?

Comment: I did try to debug with Firefox + FireBug but did not get anything useful back

Comment: try .click(function(e){ etc.. because e is not undefinied n your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was not actually in the aspx, but inside the controller.  I was returning :-

```
return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

which apparently is wrong since there is nothing to return.  I changed it to :-

```
return Json(new { ViewModel = viewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and now its working!

Thanks for all your help and time!

Answer (score 0):

Because getJson does not finishing.
it must be something like this `var url = "/Home/LoadResXFile";`

Answer (score 0):

the callback function will not be called on all the cases, if the URL you called returs a 500 OR 404, then it will not be called.
try adding a new function called .error(),

```
$.getJson(url,data,function(){
})
.error(){
alert("error");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The getJSON call is asynchronous, and the alert should fire within some seconds.

The reason is that getJSON doesn't work because the URL is malformed.

```
var url = "http://someurl/Home/LoadResXFile"; //maybe also extension needed.
```

[see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

There is another error:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

But e is not defined: change the click to this

```
$("#btnLoadData").click(function(e){
```

Comment: ok removed the e.preventDefault();  My problem is that I have already done something similar in another project, and the url was a relative path, such as "../Controller/Action" and that was working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like fiddler, or firebug can you see the .getJSON HTTP request being made?

My guess is that this request is failing, possibly due to the URI being incorrect for example.

Comment: yes it is the URI, however I do not know why.  In another project, that same format worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#btnLoadData', function () {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")";
            var postData = ({ value : $("#ResXName").val(), langID : $("#LangID").val()});
            $.getJSON(url, postData , function (data) {
                alert('clicked!');
            });
        });
    });
```

This should work.